# Jquery Remove Children of Element with out deleting one

Tags: jquery

I have a div structure

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child_item">Data </div>
    <div class="child_item">Data </div>
    <div class="child_item">Data </div>
</div>
```

I jquery how do i delete all child nodes of class "Parent" with leaving just one?

the resultant DOM would be parent with one child.

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child_item">Data </div>
</div>
```

EDIT :

```
$('.parent .child_item').not(':first').remove()
```

This only remove the first child for one div call. What if i have many parent divs like

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child_item">Data A</div>
    <div class="child_item">Data B</div>
    <div class="child_item">Data C</div>
</div>
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child_item">Data A</div>
    <div class="child_item">Data B</div>
    <div class="child_item">Data C</div>
</div> ........
```

And the Result should be this.

```
<div class="parent">
        <div class="child_item">Data A</div>
    </div>
<div class="parent">
        <div class="child_item">Data A</div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.parent .child_item').not(':first').remove()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  $(".parent .child_item").not(':eq(0)').remove();
    //or
    $('.parent .child_item').not(':first').remove();
```

reference **[:eq()](http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/)** and **[:first](http://api.jquery.com/first-selector/)**

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
$('.parent > .child_item:not(:first)').remove();
```

This will remove all the child elements except the first one.

[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/7XhCZ/)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.parent').each(function (index){
    $(this).find('.child_item').not(':eq(0)').remove();
});
```

This will remove all childs from Parent except first one.